# Limit of a continued product $\prod_{r=3}^n \frac{(r^3+3r)^2}{r^6-64} $ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: limits, infinite-product

Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty }\prod_{r=3}^n \frac{(r^3+3r)^2}{r^6-64} $

I don't have any ideas on how to approach the problem. Hints or solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Try taking the logarithm and writing terms as $\log(1+\epsilon_r) $ where $\epsilon_r$ is something small. Then...

Comment: At first sight I would also say that there is no reason a priori why this should have a cool closed form, but for sure you can provide bounds...

Comment: Isn't this question from FIITJEE AITS?

Comment: @AnkitSaha yeah it is

Comment: It was on IMC 2019, Day 1, Problem 1.

Comment: @AnkitSaha lot of questions in the AITS are just directly picked up from olympiads and competitions, I've noticed they especially like AIME problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you factor the general term, you get:

$$\frac{r^2 \left(r^2+3\right)^2}{(r-2) (r+2)
   \left(r^2-2 r+4\right) \left(r^2+2 r+4\right)}$$

Notice that $r^2-2r + 4 = (r-1)^2 + 3,\ r^2+2r + 4 = (r+1)^2+3,$
So the product telescopes: and almost everything cancels. (the final answer is $\frac{72}7.)$